# Constructor error while creating an empty dataset in weka

Tags: java, matlab, constructor, weka

I am trying to classify an instance using the classifyInstance method (described in weka's documentation [here](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Classifier.html)) using the Matlab environment.

This method require the instance to be link to a dataset. I am trying to use [this constructor](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/Instances.html#Instances(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList,%20int)) to create an empty dataset with the following matlab code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList.*;
import weka.core.*;
import weka.core.Instances.*;


attInfo = java.util.ArrayList;

attInfo.add(weka.core.Attribute('att1'));
attInfo.add(weka.core.Attribute('att2'));
attInfo.add(weka.core.Attribute('att3'));

dataset= weka.core.Instances(java.lang.String('relation'), attInfo, 2);
```

When I try to run this code matlab return me the following error:

> No constructor 'weka.core.Instances' with matching signature found.
>
> Error in file_name (line 109) dataset =
>   weka.core.Instances(java.lang.String('relation'), attInfo, 5);

What is wrong with the parameters of my constructor?

Comment: not sure about `java.lang.String('relation')` shouldn't it just be `"relation"`? > `dataset= weka.core.Instances("relation", attInfo, 2);`

Comment: Since I'm using Matlab, the strings are defined using '...'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up finding the solution of the problem. The constructor accept a signature which use the deprecated class [FastVector](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/FastVector.html). I just added a snapshot of my code in case it might help someone.

```
attInfo = FastVector();

attInfo.addElement(weka.core.Attribute('att1'));
attInfo.addElement(weka.core.Attribute('att2'));
attInfo.addElement(weka.core.Attribute('att3'));

% build the class attribute
classValues = FastVector();
classValues.addElement(java.lang.String('0'));
classValues.addElement(java.lang.String('1'));

attInfo.addElement(Attribute('Class', classValues));

% create the dataset and define the class attribute
dataset = Instances('relation', attInfo, 1);
dataset.setClassIndex(dataset.numAttributes() -1);

% build the instance
Inst = weka.core.Instance(10);
for ii = 1:D.numAttributes()
    Inst.setValue(D.attribute(ii-1), 1)
end
Inst.setDataset(dataset)

% classify the instance
classifier.classifyInstance(Inst)
```

The use of java object such as `java.lang.String()` also lead to an error.

I am still curious about why this is happening, but I suspect that might be because of the version of weka that I am using (3.6.11) where the documentation might be for the version 3.7.12 .